# How to query for a unfulfilled habtm relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have Posts and Tags (Active Record using the Mysql adapter) in a HABTM relation. How should I query for Posts that have no Tags?

Answer (score 1):

You could try including the tags in your query and then iterating over the array selecting only the posts with no tags associated.

```
Post.includes(:tags).select { |post| post.tags.empty? }
```

*Note: You can also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618583/find-tags-with-articles/15623284#15623284) where I suggested an answer along these lines earlier today. Maybe some other, potentially more efficient ideas, roll in there, too. Funny how those questions fall together sometimes :-D.*

Comment: A bit inefficient, don’t you think? All this happens in memory and not sql side, which receives a response set of count(posts) times count(tags).

Comment: I'm aware of that, hoping for someone to jump in there myself. SQL joins are not my area of expertise, though. :-D

Comment: I am doing something useful with   
    where "posts.id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM tags_posts)"
but it sounds too sql-ish for my taste

Comment: You can add your own solution as an answer for people to comment on.